# CKeditor ver. 4 table is not showing

Tags: html, ckeditor, ckeditor4

So i use ckeditor version 4 for my text editor.

my concern is why the table is not showing the border inside the table (tr, td)

i've tried to add a new class inside ckeditor/content.css but it's not working

this is what i mean by not showing border:
[image: table not showing border]

meanwhile inside the editor it's showing the border:

[image]

how can I fix this?